# Moving players to groups based on their preferences

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a list of n players.
Each player p has a club c, a strength s and can chose if he wants to be in a group with other players of c or not.

In the end I want to have groups of 4 players that have a similar strength within their group.

So I sort the list by strength and put four players into a group until there aren't enough players left.

The hard part for me is to fit the players, that don't want to play against teammates.

There are cases where it is impossible to fit (e.g. 32 players, 9 from the same club and all don't want to play each other).

In all other cases the question is: Do I need to move them up or down one group?

How would I know? I could calculate the average strength of the affected groups before and after, but there can be chain reactions, where I switch a player with a player of the next group and the switched player won't fit into the current group so another switch might be necessary.

Comment: If n is pretty small, I'd just go with randomizing the group assignments and computing the solution's fairness with a fitness function.

Comment: I would sort them then do an A* search to find the best fit.  Where best fit means "sum of the differences between players in a group".

Comment: @AKX Can you elaborate on what small means? 100, 1000? Or 20 as in your example?

Comment: @btilly How would an A* implementation look like? Start at the top (or bottom) group and if players in it are the four strongest available, the branch is ok for the moment. Then when I go down I may find, that I come to an unpairable point, where I need to reverse back up and try to change the groups so that I don't get stuck again? How would I know if a better solutions exists? WIth larger numbers of players (100?) this seems to get quite expansive?

Comment: @UNeverNo "small" depends on your patience. With a large number of people who refuse to be in groups with one another the random approach may take a while to get a solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small toy implementation of something like this in Python; it either generates random, novel solutions or mutates the current best solution in hopes it's better.

The solutions are scored by a fitness function that returns zero if the solution is completely invalid (i.e. has groups that has players that do not want to play against friends), or otherwise the inverse of the standard deviation between group strengths (so higher score is better).

```
import random
import statistics


def make_solution(player_infos: list[dict], group_size=4):
    """
    Make a solution by shuffling the players and grouping them.
    """
    players = player_infos.copy()
    random.shuffle(players)
    groups = []
    group = None
    while players:
        player = players.pop()
        if group is None:
            group = [player]
            groups.append(group)
        else:
            group.append(player)
        if len(group) == group_size:
            group = None
    return groups


def compute_group_strength(group: list[dict]) -> float:
    return sum(p["strength"] for p in group)


def is_group_ok(group: list[dict]) -> bool:
    """
    Check if a group is valid.
    """
    if all(p["allow_same_club"] for p in group):
        return True
    clubs = {p["club"] for p in group}
    return len(clubs) == len(group)  # no same club


def score_solution(solution):
    """
    Score a solution. The higher the score, the better the solution.
    """
    if not all(is_group_ok(group) for group in solution):
        return 0
    # Solution is good if groups have a similar strength
    strengths = [compute_group_strength(group) for group in solution]
    return 1 / statistics.stdev(strengths)


def mutate_solution(solution):
    """
    Mutate a solution by swapping a player between two groups.
    """
    new_solution = [group.copy() for group in solution]
    group1, group2 = random.sample(new_solution, 2)
    g1_player = random.choice(group1)
    g2_player = random.choice(group2)
    group1.remove(g1_player)
    group2.remove(g2_player)
    group1.append(g2_player)
    group2.append(g1_player)
    return new_solution


def multi_mutate_solution(solution):
    for mutation in range(random.randint(1, 10)):
        new_solution = mutate_solution(solution)
        if score_solution(new_solution):
            # Don't continue mutating if the solution is not valid
            solution = new_solution
    return solution


def main():
    rng = random.Random(42)

    player_infos = [
        {
            "name": f"Player {x}",
            "club": f"Club {rng.randint(1, 5)}",
            "strength": round(rng.uniform(1, 10), 1),
            "allow_same_club": rng.random() < 0.7,
        }
        for x in range(20)
    ]

    best_score = 0
    best_solution = None
    for attempt in range(1, 100_000):
        if best_solution and random.random() < 0.5:
            solution = multi_mutate_solution(best_solution)
        else:
            solution = make_solution(player_infos)
        score = score_solution(solution)
        if score > best_score:
            print(attempt, "Found:", score)
            best_score = score
            best_solution = solution
    print("===")
    print("Best score:", best_score)
    print("Standard deviation:", statistics.stdev(compute_group_strength(group) for group in best_solution))
    for i, group in enumerate(best_solution, 1):
        print(f"Group {i} strength: {compute_group_strength(group)}")
        for player in group:
            print(
                f'  {player["name"]}: {player["club"]}, '
                f'{player["strength"]} (allow same? {player["allow_same_club"]})'
            )
        print()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output could be e.g.

```
Group 1 strength: 19.5
  Player 13: Club 5, 9.0 (allow same? True)
  Player 8: Club 2, 2.9 (allow same? False)
  Player 10: Club 3, 6.4 (allow same? False)
  Player 0: Club 1, 1.2 (allow same? True)

Group 2 strength: 19.400000000000002
  Player 4: Club 5, 1.2 (allow same? True)
  Player 17: Club 4, 6.7 (allow same? True)
  Player 18: Club 3, 4.2 (allow same? True)
  Player 14: Club 2, 7.3 (allow same? True)

Group 3 strength: 19.8
  Player 6: Club 3, 8.3 (allow same? True)
  Player 2: Club 5, 1.8 (allow same? True)
  Player 12: Club 4, 1.7 (allow same? True)
  Player 15: Club 2, 8.0 (allow same? False)

Group 4 strength: 19.4
  Player 5: Club 5, 4.8 (allow same? True)
  Player 19: Club 1, 6.5 (allow same? True)
  Player 1: Club 2, 2.3 (allow same? True)
  Player 11: Club 4, 5.8 (allow same? False)

Group 5 strength: 19.7
  Player 9: Club 1, 1.8 (allow same? True)
  Player 3: Club 1, 1.8 (allow same? True)
  Player 16: Club 2, 8.8 (allow same? True)
  Player 7: Club 2, 7.3 (allow same? True)
```

Comment: The problem asks for the range of strengths within each group to be small, not for groups to wind up with even average strengths. So you want good together in one group and weak together in another.

Comment: Oh, well, that's just a different fitness function.